# iPhone OpenGL ES 2d background texture

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es, textures

i have a 1024 x 1024 image I use for a texture in my game for the background.

Im wondering if their is a proper way to handle drawing a large background texture.

How I am doing it currently:

```
texCoord { 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1 }
vertice { 0,0,0,height,width,0,width,height }
texCoordPointer(texCoord)
vertexPointer(vertice)

bind the texture
enable client (texCoordArr, vertexCoordArr)
drawArray
disable client (texCoordArr, vertexCoordArr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine...

I don't know if the GL|ES on the iPhone supports the glDrawTexOES extension, but if it does you may safe some lines of code. It won't make drawing any faster though.

Also some additional hints:

- try to make the texture exactly as large as the screen. There is no need to store the image in 1024*1024 if the real resolution is more around 480*320. If you zoom or pan the image it's another thing of course.
- You may save quite a bit of memory if you don't upload mipmaps for the backdrop.

Comment: Textures are required to be the power of two (64x64, 256x256 etc) up until 2.2.1, not sure about 3.0 (it does show variable-sized textures in the 3.0 simulator, can't test it on the device yet as I'm still on 2.2.1).

Comment: Yep. It's mandatory to either pad the images to a power of two or split them into smaller chunks.